# How to align an equation with equations inside of a begin{case}

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, cases, subequations

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document} \begin{align*}
    \Omega &= \begin{cases}
    X &= Y\\
    W &= X
    \end{cases}\\
    Z &= W \end{align*} \end{document}
```

Which generates

[image]

But what I really want is,

[image]

How to generate the set of aligned equations in the second figure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost there... here's a minor adjustment that uses [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) to aid in the measurement for contents across cells within the `align` and `cases`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \Omega = \begin{cases}
      abc & = \eqmakebox[RHS][l]{$defgh$} \\
        i & = \eqmakebox[RHS][l]{$j$}
    \end{cases} \kern-\nulldelimiterspace & \\
    klmno = \eqmakebox[RHS][l]{$pqrstuv$} &
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Since the `align`ment is chosen on the right-hand side of entire structure, a minor spacing correction for the right-hand side of `cases` is necessary.

If needed, you can use `\eqmakebox[LHS]` for the left-hand side(s) as well.

Comment: ...however, this is not the intended use of `cases`. That is, the alignment `&` within `cases` is meant to separate a condition, not be an equation.